# How to pass a message using template_redirect

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, template-redirect

I'm using the following function to redirect a post to another using custom field. It's working just fine until I added the `line#8` to pass an ID so that I can grab it in to the post (to where was redirected), and show a custom message that, you are redirected from *that* particular post:

```
function project_do_redirect() {
    if( !is_singular( 'mycpt' ) && !is_single() )
        return;

    global $post;
    $redirect_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'redirect', true );
    $redirect_url = $redirect_post_id ? get_permalink( $redirect_post_id ) : false;
    $redirect_url = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'redir_from', $post->ID, $redirect_url ) );
    if( $redirect_post_id ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url, 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'project_do_redirect' );
```

Problem is:
If I was redirected from post #12 to post #13, the `?redir_from=` shows `13` instead of `12`. So the thing is not actually working as expected.

So, without passing any parameter to the URL, how can I pass a message to the redirected page?

Comment: I tried this on my local installation and it works as expected: I have a post (`5`) with a post meta field called `redirect` with a value of `1`. When I visit post `5` on the frontend, I get redirected to post `1` and `?redir_from=5`, as expected. I would verify your IDs and custom meta. Can you run the following query: `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'redirect' AND post_id IN (12, 13)` and provide the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach the problem from the other side and look up the post based on the `HTTP_REFERER`, available in the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You could perform a lookup of the page based on the URL of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and get post information that way. You can also keep your 301s cleaner by not adding referrer query vars, and put the 301s in the .htaccess or Apache config as one-liners:

```
RedirectPermanent /old-path /new-path
```